# Repeating multi-lines and increment numbers in specific sections?

Tags: macro, multiple-lines

I want to create a file that has X number of entries where each entry has incremental numbers for Y. I tried recording a macro that would copy the 3 lines then edit the value but it ended up editing the wrong lines. Is a vim macro the correct way of doing this or is there another special way to duplicate lines and increment their numbers?

I realize I could just write a simple programming script that would print out this but I was already editing the file in vim and thought vim is powerful I should figure this out.

Values for
Y = 1-30

```
entry 100/1/Y
  fields value Y
  other section Y is valid
```

Results would be a multiline file that is as followed.

```
entry 100/1/1
  fields value 1
  other section 1 is valid
...
entry 100/1/30
  fields value 30
  other section 30 is valid
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A macro is certainly capable of doing this. Starting with the first three lines as a template

```
entry 100/1/1
  fields value 1
  other section 1 is valid
```

Place your cursor on the first line and execute:

`qqy2`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`jjo`<kbd>Esc</kbd>`p$`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>`j`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>`j`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>`kk0q`

- `qq` Start a macro in register `q`
- `y2`<kbd>Enter</kbd> Yank three lines
- `jjo`<kbd>Esc</kbd>`p` Copy the lines below inserting an extra blank line in-between.
- `$`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>`j`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>`j`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> Using vim's auto-increment function, increment the three numbers.
- `kk0` Set up the cursor for the next macro.
- `q` Stop recording the macro.

Now you can symply do `@q` however many times you want to repeat the macro. Or you can also do `30@q` to repeat it 30 times.

Comment: That's what I was missing the Ctrl-A feature. Thank's that's a really handy feature to know.